# How to make user-scoped credentials always visible with pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I'm trying to use user-scoped credentials solution with jenkins pipeline.
Below code is working from gui. I can choose global credentials.

```
properties([
  parameters([
    credentials(credentialType: 'com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.common.StandardUsernamePasswordCredentials',
            defaultValue: 'testValue',
            description: 'Credentials',
            name: 'CREDENTIALS',
            required: true)
  ])
])
node('master') {
  withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'CREDENTIALS', usernameVariable: 'user', passwordVariable: 'pass')]) {
      print(user)
  }
}
```

To have access to user-scoped credentials I need to click a checkbox "List user credentials", then "Only provide user credentials to trusted builds" notification appear and it's also working fine.

A problem appears when I'm trying to run job automatically with CLI from command line - job doesn't have access to my credentials even it's started by me.
Even rebuild doesn't work - I have to click "List user credentials" checkbox again.

Is there a solution to enable constant access to these credentials or disable "List user credentials" checkbox?
I don't want to keep my private credentials in Jenkins global group to give an option to use them in other jobs, but I want to have access as a default in jobs run by me.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm very interested!

Comment: Unfortunately not. I'm keeping it outside jenkins.